# div wrapper every specific index with knockout foreach loop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, foreach

I use twitter bootstrap and knockoutjs and I want to wrap col div inside row div every 6 items like so

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my knockout template :

```
//elements contain more than 6 items
<div id="main" data-bind="foreach: elements">
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

I tried with $index() method and if statement but I failed. 
Anyone have idea of how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative way to achieve this. Here it is :

In the model :

```
 self.groupedElementsIndexs = function () {
        var indexes = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < self.elements().length; i = i + 6) {
            indexes.push(i);
        }

        return indexes;
    };
```

in the template :

```
<div data-bind="foreach: groupedElementsIndexs()">
        <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: $parent.elements.slice($data, $data + 6)">
```

For the moment it work well like that for me.

Comment: Just a thought. This seems overly complex for what you are trying to achieve??

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using virtual elements to do this:

```
<div class="row">
<!-- ko foreach: elements-->

<!-- ko if: index() % 6 === 0 -->
</div>
<div class="row">
<!-- /ko -->

    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Comment: I tried but it does not work. I get Message: Cannot find closing comment tag to match: ko foreach: elements.

Comment: For the moment I found an alternative way. I will add it as an answer

Comment: I'm guessing that it doesn't like the two virtual elements in a row, I'll have a think about that.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. This seems overly complex for what you are trying to achieve?

Appreciate this may be demo code familiarising yourself with techniques.

Would seriously avoid complex code statements in your view they are hard to debug.

Would suggest:

```
<div class="row">
<!-- ko foreach: elements1-->
<div class="col-md-2"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>

<div class="row">
<!-- ko foreach: elements2-->
<div class="col-md-2"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Write the code to split this up in your viewModel.

Comment: That's true, but how you create elements1 and elements2 ? because the number of elements may vary...